# Why can open intervals be used to calculate rate of change?

Tags: functions

I was watching [this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/algebra-functions/average_rate_of_change/v/average-rate-of-change-when-function-defined-by-equation)

**Question** : On which interval does $y(x)$ have an average rate of change of $\frac{1}{2}$?

The first option is $-2 < x < 2$

The video narrator just puts in $-2$ and $2$ into the function to calculate the change.

---

But why? Isn't it an open interval? Aren't $-2$ and $2$ *outside* the interval?

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: @grdgfgr - But why?

Comment: How much contribution could 2 points could have in comparison to an interval of infinitely many points. Closed/Open interval will matter only if something unusual happens at the edges.

Answer (score 1):

You are technically right, and your critical sense is a plus when doing mathematics.

The average rate of change of a function $f$ is defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$ as
$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$

Graphically, this can be seen as the slope of the straight line connecting the end points $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$.

In the case of an open interval, there are no endpoints. We can see what value $f$ takes *when approaching the endpoints* by using limits. In the previous formule, substitute $f(a)$ by
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow a^{+}} f(x)
$$
and $f(b)$ by
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow b^{-}} f(x)
$$

In this video, the function $y$ was clearly continuous (a polynomial), such that we had $\forall z \in [a, b]$
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow z} f(x) = f(z)
$$
and the narrator could indeed just 'plug in' 2 and -2.

If you haven't had any courses on limits and continuity, ignore what I just said. Just imagine that for a continuous function (a function whose graph is non-interrupted; can be drawn without lifting the pencil) the value near the endpoints of an interval approaches the value in the endpoints as one gets closer and closer to the endpoints.

Comment: *In this video, the function y was clearly continuous* - But then why does plugging in something like 0 and 4 result in a rate of change of -2? If the function is continuous shouldn't the rate of change be same too?

Comment: @discussedtree Consider the following plot of a part of a parabola: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+-x%C2%B2+%2B+4+from+-2+to+2) . Imagine this is a mountain you'd be willing to climb from left to right. The first part (from -2 to -1) is the steepest; here the average change is 3. The second part (from -1 to 0) is easier; the average rate of change is 1. From then on, the descend begins. In fact, between the beginning and the end (-2 and 2) the average rate of change is zero, expressing that these points are at the same height.

Comment: @discussedtree A staight line (function looks like f(x) = a*x + b for some constants a and b) has constant rate of change, other curves (which actually _curve_) have a changing rate of change.

Comment: Ok, now if I input (0, 5.33350106) wouldn't plugging them in result in a wrong answer? [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=1/8+x^3+-+x^2+graph&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=OhpoVeWBL9K1uATylYOoCA)

Comment: The line of the function changes direction after that point

Comment: Or if I input (-2, 0.1) in the graph that you have linked, wouldn't plugging in -2 and 0.1 give the wrong answer? The direction changes at after 0.

Comment: No, this would not give a wrong answer, but it does show why the average rate of change does not always tell you everything you would like to know. In my example, plugging in -2 and 2 yields 0 as a resykt, which suggests that the function doesn't change between -2 and 2 on that interval, but it does! So to answer your question: plugging in (-2, 0.1) would give you the right answer. Just be aware that the average rate of change indeed doesn't tell you everything.

Comment: Suppose the we are asked to find it for the interval (-2, 0.1). Wouldn't plugging in 0.1 (which is *outside* the interval and also changes) result in the wrong answer for the interval (-2, 0.1)?

Comment: Ah, it is beginning to click! I suppose you can plug in the -2 and 2 only if it is a continuous function, not if it is non-continuous. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Indeed, for continuous functions, you have little work to do. Glad I could help.